# Understanding Spark MLlib LDA input format

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, lda

I am trying to implement LDA using Spark MLlib.

But I am having difficulty understanding input format. I was able to run its sample implementation to take input from a file which contains only number's as shown :

```
1 2 6 0 2 3 1 1 0 0 3
1 3 0 1 3 0 0 2 0 0 1
1 4 1 0 0 4 9 0 1 2 0
2 1 0 3 0 0 5 0 2 3 9
3 1 1 9 3 0 2 0 0 1 3
4 2 0 3 4 5 1 1 1 4 0
2 1 0 3 0 0 5 0 2 2 9
1 1 1 9 2 1 2 0 0 1 3
4 4 0 3 4 2 1 3 0 0 0
2 8 2 0 3 0 2 0 2 7 2
1 1 1 9 0 2 2 0 0 3 3
4 1 0 0 4 5 1 3 0 1 0
```

I followed 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda

I understand the output format of this as explained [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-interpret-java-LDA-sample-output-td23963.html).

My use case is very simple, I have one data file with some sentences.
I want to convert this file into corpus so that to pass it to `org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.LDA.run()`.

My doubt is about what those numbers in input represent which is then zipWithIndex and passed to LDA? Is it like number 1 appearing everywhere represent same word or it is some kind of count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert your sentences into vectors.

```
val documents: RDD[Seq[String]] = sc.textFile("yourfile").map(_.split("      ").toSeq)

val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
val tf: RDD[Vector] = hashingTF.transform(documents)
val idf = new IDF().fit(tf)
val tfidf: RDD[Vector] = idf.transform(tf)
val corpus = tfidf.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).cache()

 // Cluster the documents into three topics using LDA
val ldaModel = new LDA().setK(3).run(corpus)
```

Read more about TF_IDF vectorization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf)

Comment: Thanks I finally understand this.